# How to take php loop value in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, performance, google-maps, distance

I have two constant value lat1 and lng1. now i want to take these value in javascript but it i could not do that. While using script outside of php it is working but when use within php it is not working. I am trying to show google map with distance that's why i have to take some value from my database using while loop. Help me guys. My php code given below

```
**
$qry="SELECT * FROM markers";
$run= mysqli_query($connect,$qry);
while($row=$run->fetch_array()){
    $lat2=$row["lat"];
    $lng2=$row["lng"];
    echo "$lat2"."and"."$lng2"."<br>";
    echo '
        <script>
            var lat1=<?php echo $lat1; ?>;
            var lng1=<?php echo $lng1; ?>;
            var lat2=<?php echo $lat2; ?>;
            var lng2=<?php echo $lng2; ?>;
            var R = 6371; 
            var rlat1 = lat1.toRadians();
            var rlat2 = lat2.toRadians();
            var rlng1 = lng1.toRadians();
            var rlng2 = lng2.toRadians();
            // var diflat= (lat2-lat1).toRadians();
            // var diflng = (lng2-lng1).toRadians();
            var x = (rlng2-rlng1) * Math.cos((rlat1+rlat2)/2);
            var y = (rlat2-rlat1);
            var d = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y) * R;
            document.write(d);
        </script>
    ';
}
```

Comment: any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is an error in your script

```
echo '
        <script>
            var lat1=<?php echo $lat1; ?>;
```

consider, closing the php tag and write simple html, then going back as needed like this

```
?>
        <script>
            var lat1=<?php echo $lat1; ?>;
```

your whole code would be something like:

```
<?php 
$qry="SELECT * FROM markers";
$run= mysqli_query($connect,$qry);
while($row=$run->fetch_array()){
    $lat2=$row["lat"];
    $lng2=$row["lng"];
    echo "$lat2"."and"."$lng2"."<br>";
?>
        <script>
            var lat1=<?php echo $lat1; ?>;
            var lng1=<?php echo $lng1; ?>;
            var lat2=<?php echo $lat2; ?>;
            var lng2=<?php echo $lng2; ?>;
            var R = 6371; 
            var rlat1 = lat1.toRadians();
            var rlat2 = lat2.toRadians();
            var rlng1 = lng1.toRadians();
            var rlng2 = lng2.toRadians();
            // var diflat= (lat2-lat1).toRadians();
            // var diflng = (lng2-lng1).toRadians();
            var x = (rlng2-rlng1) * Math.cos((rlat1+rlat2)/2);
            var y = (rlat2-rlat1);
            var d = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y) * R;
            document.write(d);
        </script>;
        <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<script>
            var lat1='.$lat1.';
            var lng1='.$lng1.';
            var lat2='.$lat2.';
            var lng2='.$lng2.';
            var R = 6371; 
            var rlat1 = lat1.toRadians();
            var rlat2 = lat2.toRadians();
            var rlng1 = lng1.toRadians();
            var rlng2 = lng2.toRadians();
            // var diflat= (lat2-lat1).toRadians();
            // var diflng = (lng2-lng1).toRadians();
            var x = (rlng2-rlng1) * Math.cos((rlat1+rlat2)/2);
            var y = (rlat2-rlat1);
            var d = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y) * R;
            document.write(d);
        </script>
     ';
```

What I changed was removing nested PHP tags. Instead, you should concatenate the echoed string with a dot ([PHP echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)). This may not guarantee you a working map, but at least will set your PHP straight.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace you code like this:

```
<?php 
$qry="SELECT * FROM markers";
$run= mysqli_query($connect,$qry);
while($row=$run->fetch_array()){
    $lat2=$row["lat"];
    $lng2=$row["lng"];
    echo "$lat2"."and"."$lng2"."<br>";
    echo '
        <script>
            var lat1='.$lat1.';
            var lng1='.$lng1.';
            var lat2='.$lat2.';
            var lng2='.$lng2.';
            var R = 6371; 
            var rlat1 = lat1.toRadians();
            var rlat2 = lat2.toRadians();
            var rlng1 = lng1.toRadians();
            var rlng2 = lng2.toRadians();
            // var diflat= (lat2-lat1).toRadians();
            // var diflng = (lng2-lng1).toRadians();
            var x = (rlng2-rlng1) * Math.cos((rlat1+rlat2)/2);
            var y = (rlat2-rlat1);
            var d = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y) * R;
            document.write(d);
        </script>
    ';
}
?>
```